# Redial menu from top right corner

Tags: android

I am developing an app having redial menu,which shows different buttons.Lots of demo of redial menu are available,But i want to show the redial menu from top right corner.please help or any suggestion.

Comment: I suggest you keep searching and/or adapt one of the "lots" of radial menus to work the way you want it to.

Comment: Beyond that, please explain *in detail* what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Answer (score 1):

The standard button placement for ActionBar is the top-right corner.  If you add button to your ActionBar using the standard menu metaphor, you can place a button to do whatever you want in the top right corner.